# Использование потоков для распараллеливания

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++builder

Пишу на C++ Builder. Имеется динамический список объектов. Для каждого объекта рассчитывается оценка. Сейчас такой расчет для всех объектов списка реализован в цикле. Поскольку алгоритм расчета оценки использует только данные конкретного объекта, имеет смысл выполнять его одновременно для нескольких объектов сразу в параллельных потоках. Что я собственно и попробовал сделать:

```
cEstimationThread * pFirstThread=new cEstimationThread(true);
cEstimationThread * pSecondThread=new cEstimationThread(true);

for(cChromosome * curChromosome=startChromosome;curChromosome;)
{
    if(!pFirstThread->bRunning)
    {
        pFirstThread->SetValuesForEstimation(
            curChromosome,
            arrUnitSets,
            arrUncertSets,
            iNumOfVars,
            iNumOfSets,
            iNumOfUnitSets,
            iCoverWeight);
        pFirstThread->Resume();
        curChromosome=curChromosome->next;
    }
    if(curChromosome)
    {
        if(!pSecondThread->bRunning)
        {
            pSecondThread->SetValuesForEstimation(
                curChromosome,
                arrUnitSets,
                arrUncertSets,
                iNumOfVars,
                iNumOfSets,
                iNumOfUnitSets,
                iCoverWeight);
            pSecondThread->Resume();
            curChromosome=curChromosome->next;
        }
    }
    while(pFirstThread->bRunning&&pSecondThread->bRunning);
}
while(pFirstThread->bRunning||pSecondThread->bRunning);

pFirstThread->FreeOnTerminate=true;
pSecondThread->FreeOnTerminate=true;

pFirstThread->Terminate();
pSecondThread->Terminate();
```

Здесь создаются два потока `pFirstThread` и `pSecondThread`, затем в первый поток заносится ссылка на очередной объект `curChromosome`, указатели на динамические массивы `arrUnitSets`, `arrUncertSets` (используются только для чтения) и еще несколько переменных для расчета (заносятся по значению, используются только для чтения). Потом первый поток запускается на выполнение. Затем, следующий объект заносится во второй поток и т.д.

После этого в строке `while(pFirstThread->bRunning&&pSecondThread->bRunning)`, как мне кажется, я реализовал ожидание выполнения обоих потоков (переменная `bRunning` в начале выполнения кода потока принимает значение `true`, а после выполнения `false`). Как только список объектов заканчивается, потоки уничтожаются.

Код, как ни странно :), оказался нерабочим. При пошаговой отладке происходит что-то странное: то выполняется код основного потока, то `pFirstThread`, при чем непонятно, чем это определяется.

В связи с этим два вопроса:

1. как в случае с двумя процессорами ОС (WinXP) определяет, какой поток запустить, а какой приостановить (все равно же они не будут выполняться одновременно)?
2. можно ли таким образом синхронизировать выполнение потоков: `while(pFirstThread->bRunning&&pSecondThread->bRunning)`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Потоки выполняются одновременно :-) Если даже процессор один - тогда они будут на микроуровне попеременно выполняться. На макро (для пользователя) - как будто одновременно.
2. лучше - WaitForSingleObject или WaitForMultipleObject, IMHO. Или хотя бы объявить bRunning как volatile. Как и все переменные, которые могут быть модифицированы из нескольких потоков.

Answer (score 0):

Для синхронизации потоков лучше использовать специальные средства: мьютексы и семафоры. Или переменные с атомарным доступом.

Можно сделать, например, так: в цикле пускать потоки и засыпать, а просыпаться по событию пришедшему по окончанию другого потока.

```
do
{
    // Пустить поток
} while () // Ждать события
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за быстрые ответы. Перепробовал много вариантов, но пришел в итоге ни к чему.  Как я понимаю, WaitForMultipleObjects позволяет управлять доступом потоков к некоторой критической секции. У меня же задача поставлена так, что вся программа - это критическая секция, а то, что внутри потокового класса, - это не критическая секция. Может, я не понимаю сам принцип.

Вот моя функция Execute:

```
void __fastcall cEstimationThread::Execute()
{
    EstimateFitnessesOfIndividuals();
}
```

EstimateFitnessesOfIndividuals() - функция для расчета данных, реализована внутри потокового класса.

Вот измененнная функция, где потоки создаются и вызываются.

```
void cBFGAConverter::EstimateFitnessesOfIndividuals(cChromosome *startChromosome)
{
    int j, k;
    int iEstimation;
    int iNumOfCoveredUnitSets;

    cEstimationThread *pFirstThread = new cEstimationThread (true);
    cEstimationThread *pSecondThread = new cEstimationThread (true);
    HANDLE *hmy_threads = new HANDLE[2];
    hmy_threads[0] = (void *) pFirstThread->Handle;
    hmy_threads[1] = (void *) pSecondThread->Handle;

    for (cChromosome * curChromosome = startChromosome; curChromosome;)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject((void *)pFirstThread->Handle, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            pFirstThread->SetValuesForEstimation(
                curChromosome, arrUnitSets,
                arrUncertSets, iNumOfVars,
                iNumOfSets,
                iNumOfUnitSets,
                iCoverWeight);
            pFirstThread->Resume ();
            curChromosome = curChromosome->next;
        }
        if (curChromosome)
        {
            if (WaitForSingleObject((void *)pSecondThread->Handle, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                pSecondThread->SetValuesForEstimation (curChromosome,
                    arrUnitSets,
                    arrUncertSets,
                    iNumOfVars, iNumOfSets,
                    iNumOfUnitSets,
                    iCoverWeight);
                pSecondThread->Resume ();
                curChromosome = curChromosome->next;
            }
        }

        WaitForMultipleObjects (2, (void *const *) hmy_threads, false, INFINITE);
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects (2, (void *const *) hmy_threads, true, INFINITE);

    pFirstThread->FreeOnTerminate = true;
    pSecondThread->FreeOnTerminate = true;

    pFirstThread->Terminate ();
    pSecondThread->Terminate ();

    return;
}
```